# How to handle + signs in URL filename

Tags: c#

I am receiving errors while downloading files containing + characters in the filename.

In my c# MVC web application I have a page which contains links to download images.

I retrieve the filename from my database then pass it to my controller to handle downloads.

This specific filename is generating errors because of the + character.

b51535d5-4ea3-45ae-bda4-332a0ce19ee8TopDogg+Gomez.jpg

While debugging the application I noticed the file name that’s sent to the controller excludes the + sign and has a space instead.

This caused the server to return a file not found error

```
public ActionResult DownloadImageFile(string filename)
{
    filename = "https://marvment.com/" + filename;

    var type = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    var path = Path.GetFileName(filename);

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var buffer = client.DownloadData(filename);
        return File(buffer, type.ToString(), path);
    }
}
```

How can I prevent the filename from beign url encoded ?

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: "How can I prevent the filename from beign url encoded" - you are not performing any encoding at all. So not sure what you are trying to prevent... I assume you understand that should not be constructing Url this way as it produce invalid Uri (unlike for example `UriBuilder`), so it would be useful to explain why you you think you need to "prevent encoding".

Answer (score 0):

There are special characters that mean specific things in URLs.  If the character is part of the URL itself and shouldn't carry such a meaning, it needs to be [URL-encoded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
b51535d5-4ea3-45ae-bda4-332a0ce19ee8TopDogg%2BGomez.jpg
```

Comment: The problem is that the + sign is removed and replaced with a space before it gets to the method in the controller..

Comment: @user1526912: What's causing that?  Whatever initiates this request also needs to URL-encode the value.